# Can I call get property from a different method for an object value if I passed the object as a parameter in c#?

Tags: c#, properties, stack-overflow

```
    public static void OpenAccount()
    {
     
        Console.WriteLine("Please provide the below details:");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your First Name:");
        String accFirstName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your Last Name:");
        String accLastName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount to be deposited:");
        double amount = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()) ;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your mobile number:");
        int accMobileNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid location:");
        string accLocation = Console.ReadLine();

        Account a = new Account(701,accFirstName,accLastName,amount,accMobileNumber,accLocation,true);
        Console.WriteLine("Congratulations!! Your account is created with ABCD Bank. Your acccount details are below:");
        
        Console.WriteLine("Account Number:" + a._accNo);
        Console.WriteLine("Account Name" +a[1] +" "+ a[2]);
        Console.WriteLine("Account Mobile No:" +a[3]);
        Console.WriteLine("Amount Available: " +a[4]);
        Console.WriteLine("Account Location: " + a[5]);
        if (a._isActive)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Account Status: ACTIVE");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Account Status: INACTIVE!!!!");
        }

        ChooseOption(8,a);



    }
```

//Then I am passing the above object with values to another method and trying to access those values:

//if I am using an indexer I am able to access it otherwise with get and set properties it's not working. Can anyone explain why?

```
 public static void CheckBalance(Account a)
    {
        
        
        Console.WriteLine(a._accAmount);//Throwing stack overflow error
        Console.WriteLine(a[0]); //recieving the value no error
        


    }
```

I want to be able to get & set the values for the object via get and set property.

Comment: You need to show the Account class code for this. Btw, by C# naming conventions, an underscore and a lowercase letter indicates a private variable (if _accAmount is a public property, then it should be called AccAmount).

Comment: @Peter you probably mean "private field", not "private variable"

Comment: @Klaus, you are right, that would be the correct wording in the C# world, but there are many ways to say the same thing, depending on the context, usually all of them are correct. For example, in OOP context you would say "private class member", in C++ context "private variable" and so on. We shouldn't trip on wordings when the mean the same, IMHO :)

Comment: @Peter, can you please take a look at the account code

Answer (score 0):

The _accAmount property in the Account class contains the key to the problem.

```
public double _accAmount
{
    get
    {
        return _accAmount;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_isActive)
        {
            _accAmount = value;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Account INACTIVE!!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

The _accAmount property trys to return "_accAmount" which is self referential (references itself). It will call itself again and again until the stack overflows. On the other hand, the indexer returns "amount" (a variable) when the index is 4, so there is no problem. The implementation of _accAmount should return or set the "amount" variable instead of referencing itself as shown below to fix the problem.

```
public double _accAmount
{
    get
    {
        return amount;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_isActive)
        {
            amount = value;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Account INACTIVE!!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @AnkitaRoy Please accept the answer if this answers your question satisfactorily.